# Accessing form via browser back button is not triggering "Confirm form resubmit"

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, mediawiki

I have a company Wiki powered by MediaWiki. I have written code to add a page-locking feature, so that when a user edits a page, they get a 15 minute lock on the page which they can renew at any point before it expires.

If the user edits a page, and then clicks save, and then clicks the browser's back button to return to the edit form, everything looks normal and the user thinks everything is okay, but here's the kicker: it doesn't create a new lock on the page. The message that tells the user has a lock on the page, but I think it's just because its a cached version of the page; the expire time in the message is the expire time for the lock from the **first** time they edited, **not** using the back button.

I have tried adding HTML `meta` tags to the page inside the `head` tags to invalidate the cache/not cache the edit page, but this doesn't work because the MediaWiki PHP page generator overrides this.

Right now I have a very sloppy fix; I use JavaScript to simulate pressing the browser forward button, e.g. Move forward in history, on the edit page. If a newer history item doesn't exist (e.g. They clicked the actual "edit" button instead of using the browser back button) it just does nothing, but if they accessed the edit page via the back button, it briefly shows the page for about a second until the JavaScript loads and then redirects forward in history (putting them back where they were before hitting the back button). Yes, this works, but it is a very poor solution, in my opinion, as it's not very seamless/user friendly and could confuse users or make them think something is wrong with their browser.

A better solution would be to force the user to resubmit the form, thus opening a "fresh" version of the edit page, and I actually am not sure why it is not already doing this. What I mean by that is, when the user accesses the edit page via the browser back button, I want it to show the "Confirm Form Resubmit" error page. Google Chrome's for example:

[image: error example]

I think this will fix the problem by forcing a resubmit of the form, which I believe will then create an *actual* page-lock. Correct me if I am wrong.

I don't think much of the page locking code is very relevant, because the reason for the problem is just that the back button is bringing them to a cached version of the page and not a "fresh" version, but if you think otherwise, feel free to ask for it. Just let me know what parts of the code to post and I will add them.

Comment: after post, use redirection for the same page.

Comment: um. what? Could you clarify what you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @devpro comment is related to your questions, but its meaning should be reversed. Mediawiki **already** have mechanism that prevents user from seeing "resubmit" warning when he clicks "refresh" or "back" button later - after form was submitted it redirects user (via 302 redirect) to the page that was edited.

This way, if user will decide to refresh page right after edit or if he posted form, then navigated to another page and pressed "back" button - he will not re-submit form again.

It is almost impossible to change this behavior ( it is buried deeply in Mediawiki core ), though, event if it would be possible - you should not go this way until you want to get your editors totally confused.

There is no solution at back-end side, because the form page is loaded from browser cache, but you still can prevent this using js and Mediawiki JS interface can help with that:

Create extension that adds JS script to 'view' action, make it track variable `wgPostEdit` ([see more](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/JavaScript)) which gets populated only after page was saved. Once this variable is set - use [this trick](https://gist.github.com/w33tmaricich/7009931) to display a warning when user will try to navigate back.

Answer (score 1):

Find some hook which gives you the OuputPage (I'm not that familiar with them but maybe [OutputPageBeforeHTML](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/OutputPageBeforeHTML)?) and call `OuputPage::enableClientCache(false)` on edit pages.